# How to write a string without quotes to a file with MRJob?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mrjob

I am using MRJob to yield values and write them to a file...

I have the following, where I yield a string(boom) as a key and an int(sum) as a value:

```
boom = str(", ".join(key)).strip('"')
yield boom, sum
```

But I get an output that writes quotation marks (") around the string.  How can I write these strings without the quotes?

Here's my output:

```
Running step 1 of 2...
Creating temp directory /tmp/flight.edd5103.20190209.202746.795079
Running step 2 of 2...
job output is in /tmp/flight.edd5103.20190209.202746.795079/output
Streaming final output from /tmp/flight.edd5103.20190209.202746.795079/output...
"Canada, France"        24
"Mexico, France"        18
"United States, France" 30
"United States, Germany"        10
Removing temp directory /tmp/flight.edd5103.20190209.202746.795079...
```

Comment: there are no quotes, you probably get the representation of the strings. [mcve] please

Comment: [mcve] please. This is too unclear. This is a duplicate of ... something

Comment: aren't you feeding your tuple to a csv / tsv dump? csv adds double quotes when needed